# unable to add rows to multiindex dataframe if values are both numeric

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

something's definitely wrong here. i can update an extant numerical `MultiIndex` (e.g. `df.loc[(1,1), :]`), but i can't add a *new* row with a non-existent numerical `MultiIndex`. however, i can add a new row whose index contains at least one string! this makes little sense to me. any ideas why this would be the case?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abc'), index=[0])
df.ix[0] = 1
df = df.set_index(list('ab'))
df

Out[106]: 
     c
a b   
1 1  1

#WORKS
df.loc[(1,1), :] = 6
df

Out[107]: 
     c
a b   
1 1  6


#FAILS:
df.loc[(1,2), :] = 6
df

Out[108]: 
     c
a b   
1 1  6


#HOWEVER, THIS WORKS! (wth!?)
df.loc[('a','b'), :] = 888
df

Out[109]: 
       c
a b     
1 1    6
a b  888
```

Comment: You are on a slightely older version no? works fine in 0.14.1. IIRC their was an issue about this in 0.13.1/0.14.0 that was fixed (in those versions)

Comment: yeah, 14.0. i was going to update but i'm running stuff so i can't right now. i'll check out 14.1

Comment: yep, looks broken in 0.14.0, but works in 0.14.1.

Comment: FYI, unless you are doing this with a very small number times this is not very efficient AT ALL. It copies the frame each time. MUCH better to concat frames.

Comment: good call as well. thanks for all the info. stupid bugs!